# Is there a magnifying ruler to measure pixels?

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, safari-extension, ieaddon

I have been looking for this for a while:

There are a ton of ruler extensions for all the common browsers but I can't find **one that has a magnifying glass**. Can anyone help me out please?

I'm talking about a magnifying glass like the [Awesome Color Picker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-color-picker/flkdgmgdgnpdecpaaoggnbjcdmbnagbj) extension in Chrome:
[image: Awesome Color Picker screenshot]

The ruler extensions I've used really hurt my eyes when trying to measure anything to pixel precision.

Any browser is fine with me.

Note #1: This is not about seeing the width of elements through 'inspect element'. I need to find the precise number of pixels between any two points on a web page.

Note #2: Zooming in the browser doesn't do it either because some of the pixels change when I zoom.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you were looking for, but it might be worth checking out. It has zooming in on pixels, up to 3200%.

http://matthiasschuetz.com/pixelzoomer/

It's a FireFox add-on. I am not affiliated with the add-on at all.

Answer (score 2):

Check out xScope from IconFactory. http://xscopeapp.com I use it all the time for development layouts. It's got several tools, including rulers, guides, a tool for dynamically measuring elements, and a loupe for viewing an enlarged part of your layouts. It's not a browser plugin, but I find that this makes it actually MORE useful.

Comment: It is only for MacOSX